# sencha 2.3.1 build native app give error on windows 7

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2, package, native, sencha-cmd

"sencha app build native" give me this error:

> [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
>        **[aapt] C:\wamp\www\sencha_app\build\native-package-mobile\my_app\packager.json\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').**
>   
>   BUILD FAILED
>   C:\ADT\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\ADT\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returned: 1
>   
>   Total time: 1 second
>   ""C:/ADT/sdk\tools\android" create project --target android-19 --name my_app --activity STActivity --path "C:\wamp\www\sencha_app/build/native-package-mobile/my_app/packager.json/" --package com.pocketmedia.my_app"
>   **Could not run ant with error: 1**
>   **Failed to package application**
>   
>   [ERR] 
>   [ERR] BUILD FAILED
>   [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7
>   [ERR]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Targ
>   [ERR] et.java:413)
>   [ERR] 
>   [ERR] Total time: 13 seconds
>   [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\wamp\www\sencha_app\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:422: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\wamp\www\sencha_app.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:112: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\wamp\www\sencha_app\.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:114: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\wamp\www\sencha_app\.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:98: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\wamp\www\sencha_app\.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:7: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7

My package.json

```
{
/**
 * @cfg {String} applicationName
 * @required
 * This is the name of your application, which is displayed on the device when the app is installed. On IOS, this should match
 * the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
 */
"applicationName":"my_app",

/**
 * @cfg {String} applicationId
 * This is the name namespace for your application. On IOS, this should match the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
 */
"applicationId":"com.company.my_app",

/**
 * @cfg {String} bundleSeedId
 * A ten character string which stands before aplication ID in Apple Provisioning Portal
 */
"bundleSeedId":"KPXFEPZ6EF",

/**
 * @cfg {String} versionString
 * @required
 * This is the version of your application.
 */
"versionString":"1.0",

/**
 * @cfg {Integer} versionCode
 * @required
 * This is the integer version code of your application, or you can refer to it as a build number. Used only for Android builds.
 */
"versionCode":"1",

/**
 * @cfg {Object} icon
 * For iOS, please refer to their documentation about icon sizes:
 * https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html
 *
 * For Android, please refer to the Google Launcher icons guide:
 * http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html
 *
 * iOS 7 uses 60, 76, 120, 152 (29, 58 for the Settings app; 40, 80 for Spotlight search results).
 * iOS 6.1 and earlier uses 57, 72, 114, 144 (29, 58 for the Settings app, for Spotlight search results on iPhone; 50 and 100 for Spotlight search results on iPad).
 * Android uses 36, 48, 72, 96.
 * If you package for Android you can ignore iOS icons and vice versa.
 */
"icon": {
    "60":"resources/icons/Icon.png",
    "120":"resources/icons/Icon@2x.png",
    "76":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",
    "152":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png",
    "36":"resources/icons/Icon-36.png",
    "48":"resources/icons/Icon-48.png",
    "96":"resources/icons/Icon-96.png",
    "57":"resources/icons/Icon-57.png",
    "114":"resources/icons/Icon-57@2x.png",
    "72":"resources/icons/Icon-72.png",
    "144":"resources/icons/Icon-72@2x.png",
    "29":"resources/icons/Icon-Small.png",
    "58":"resources/icons/Icon-Small@2x.png",
    "40":"resources/icons/Icon-Small-40.png",
    "80":"resources/icons/Icon-Small-40@2x.png",
    "50":"resources/icons/Icon-Small-50.png",
    "100":"resources/icons/Icon-Small-50@2x.png"
},

/**
 * @cfg {String} inputPath
 * @required
 * This is location of your Sencha Touch 2 application, relative to this configuration file.
 */
"inputPath":"./",

/**
 * @cfg {String} outputPath
 * @required
 * This is where the built application file with be saved. Make sure that output path is not in your input path, you may get into endless recursive copying
 */
"outputPath":"../build/",

/**
 * @cfg {String} configuration
 * @required
 * This is configuration for your application. `Debug` should always be used unless you are submitting your app to an online
 * store - in which case `Release` should be specified.
 */
"configuration":"Debug",

/**
 * @cfg {String} platform
 * @required
 * This is the platform where you will be running your application. Available options are:
 *  - iOSSimulator
 *  - iOS
 *  - Android
 *  - AndroidEmulator
 */
"platform":"Android",

/**
 * @cfg {String} deviceType
 * @required
 * This is device type that your application will be running on.
 *
 * If you are developing for Android, this is not necessary.
 *
 * Available options are:
 *  - iPhone
 *  - iPad
 *  - Universal
 */
"deviceType":"Universal",

/**
 * @cfg {String} certificatePath
 * This is the location of your certificate.
 * This is required when you are developing for Android or you are developing on Windows.
 */
"certificatePath":"./appkey.keystore",

/**
 * @cfg {String} certificateAlias
 * This is the name of your certificate.
 *
 * IF you do not specify this on OSX, we will try and automatically find the certificate for you using the applicationId.
 *
 * This can be just a simple matcher. For example, if your certificate name is "iPhone Developer: Robert Dougan (ABCDEFGHIJ)", you
 * can just put "iPhone Developer".
 *
 * When using a certificatePath on Windows, you do not need to specify this.
 */
"certificateAlias":"app_keystore",

/**
 * @cfg {String} certificatePassword
 * The password which was specified during certificate export
 */
"certificatePassword":"password",

/**
 * @cfg {String} provisionProfile
 * The path to the provision profile (APP_NAME.mobileprovision) which you can create and then download from Apple's provisioning portal
 */
"provisionProfile":"",

/**
 * @cfg {String} URLScheme
 * URL scheme for communication with your application, can be empty if you don't use custom URL scheme in your project.
 */
"URLScheme":"",

/**
 * @cfg {String} notificationConfiguration
 * Notification configuration for push notifications, can be "debug", "release" or empty if you don't use push notifications in your project.
 */
"notificationConfiguration":"",

/**
 * @cfg {String} sdkPath
 * This is the path to the Android SDK, if you are developing an Android application.
 */
"sdkPath":"C:/ADT/sdk",

/**
 * @cfg {String} androidAPILevel
 * This is android API level, the version of Android SDK to use, you can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html.
 * Be sure to install corresponding platform API in android SDK manager (android_sdk/tools/android)
 */
"androidAPILevel":"19",

/**
/**
 * @cfg {Array[String]} permissions
 * Array of permissions that is used by an application (Android only) 
 * Full list of permissions for Android application can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES
 */
"permissions":[
    "INTERNET",
    "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",     
    "VIBRATE"       
],

/**
 * @cfg {Array[String]} orientations
 * @required
 * This is orientations that this application can run.
 */
"orientations": [
    "portrait"
]
```

}

My OS is **Windows 7 Home Edition 64bit**
Sencha version: 2.3.1
Sencha CMD: 4.0.4.84
Sencha tools: 2.0.0-beta3
JDK version: 1.7.0_01
Ant version: 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

> C:\wamp\www\sencha_app.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:422: The following
>   error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\wamp\www\sencha_app.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:112: The following
>   error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\wamp\www\sencha_app.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:114: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\wamp\www\sencha_app.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:98: The following
>   error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\wamp\www\sencha_app.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:7:

I had the same problem.

Installing the required SDK Platform in the Android SDK Manager fixed it for me.

Hope this helped you :P

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder under the build folder and name it res then another under res named drawable under res then copied the icon.

it worked :)